# iBeacon didEnterRegion not firing when in background and locked

Tags: ibeacon

I have an iBeacon configured as:

```
NSUUID *proximityUUID = [[NSUUID alloc] initWithUUIDString:kUUID];
self.beaconRegion = [[CLBeaconRegion alloc] initWithProximityUUID:proximityUUID identifier:kIdentifier];
self.beaconRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = NO;    
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnEntry = YES;
self.beaconRegion.notifyOnExit = YES;
```

When my app is closed and the device is locked, didEnterRegion is never fired:

```
locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region{
    [self sendLocalNotificationForBeaconRegionHello:(CLBeaconRegion *)region];
}

- (void)sendLocalNotificationForBeaconRegionHello:(CLBeaconRegion *)region
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [UILocalNotification new];

    notification.alertBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Welcome - %@", region.identifier];
    notification.alertAction = NSLocalizedString(@"View", nil);
    notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
    notification.fireDate = nil;
    notification.hasAction = false;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] presentLocalNotificationNow:notification];
}
```

The didExitRegion does get called even if the app is closed and the phone is locked. I only get a notification when entering a region when unlocking the phone.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: do you used the keychain somewhere in your start sequence?

Comment: What do you mean with keychain?

Comment: keychain = apple's secure password storage

Comment: No, I don't use the keychain in my app.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the method is getting called but the notification swallowed for some reason (although the code looks OK).  Try adding a method like below to help figure out what is going on:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didDetermineState:(CLRegionState)state forRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
    if(state == CLRegionStateInside) {
        NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState INSIDE for %@", region.identifier);
    }
    else if(state == CLRegionStateOutside) {
       NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState OUTSIDE for %@", region.identifier);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"locationManager didDetermineState OTHER for %@", region.identifier);
    }
}
```

It would also be useful to see your code in `didExitRegion` for comparison, and hear details about how you are testing enter/exit conditions (including wait times.)

Comment: I'm using the same function call for didExitRegion, but changing the message. didExitRegion gets fired about 15 to 20 seconds after leaving the iBeacon region. I've waited up to 10 minutes to get a notification for didEnterRegion, with no luck. When unlocking the phone, the notifications shows up in about 1 to 3 seconds.

Comment: See my updated answer.  I would love to see the NSLog output after you add a method like shown, and re-run your tests.

Comment: Did some testing...but got even weirder results. When connected to the laptop and debugging the app, didEnterRegion does get fired. As soon as I run the app disconnected from the laptop didEnterRegion never get fired. didExitRegion works fine when connected & disconnected from the laptop.